# remove a part at the end of string - last match only

Tags: php, string, trim

I'm using `rtrim()` to remove a part at the end of string, `, US` in my example:

```
<?php

$str = "Hello - world, c., US, US";

echo rtrim($str,", US");

?>
```

Output:

```
Hello - world, c.
```

It removed `, US, US` and i want to remove the last one only and the output should be `Hello - world, c., US`

How i can do that please?

Comment: why not just remove the last 4 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rtrim()` doesn't remove a specific string, it uses the string as a list of characters to remove at the end.

Use a regular expression replacement:

```
echo preg_replace('/, US$/', '', $str);
```

The `$` anchors the match to the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

**`substr`** + **`strrpos`** approach:

```
$str = "Hello - world, c., US, US";
echo substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, ", US"));
```

The output:

```
Hello - world, c., US
```

Comment: this is a better answer as the other one is more cpu intense which would be noticeable on a large scale.

Comment: this will give empty string if it cannot find ", US"